# howto get the size of a linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I try to get the size of a linearlayout. I get always iactualHeight=0 in the following code:

```
li=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.textviewerbuttonlayout);
li.requestLayout();
int iactualHeight=li.getLayoutParams().height;
```

My Layout is defined as follow:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:id="@+id/textviewerlayout"
android:orientation="vertical">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mywebview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="22" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textviewerbuttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
.... BUTTONS .....


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Somebody any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will not get value unitl `onCreate` finishes.so add these in `onResume()` or in `onStart()`

```
 int height= li.getHeight();
 int width = li.getWidth();
```

the other option is to use `globallayoutlistener`(if you want to get height in onCreate) so you will get notified when li(your layout) is added.

```
ViewTreeObserver observer= li.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Log.d("Log", "Height: " + li.getHeight());
                Log.d("Log", "Width: " + li.getWidth());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. in onStart I still get 0. In OnGlobalLayoutListener I get the right values. So your quick answer is very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are requesting the height too early. Take a look at [how android draws views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).

The easiest way to get the guaranteed height is to use addOnLayoutChangedListener:

```
  View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
    myView.addOnLayoutChangedListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight,
                    int oldBottom) {
                // its possible that the layout is not complete in which case
                // we will get all zero values for the positions, so ignore the event
                if (left == 0 && top == 0 && right == 0 && bottom == 0) {
                    return;
                }

               int height = top - bottom;
            }
});
```